# Error in getting value in custom dimension in google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, custom-dimensions

I got a question about extracting custom dimension in the google big query. 
This question is already asked by some people already, however, the solution is not working..

The question is, when I tried to extract the information for the custom dimension like this

```
SELECT
fullvisitorId,
visitid,
hit.hitnumber,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 1) as productCategory,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 2) as loyaltyClass,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 3) as existingCustomer
FROM [<id>.ga_sessions_20180805],UNNEST(hits) as hit
LIMIT 100
```

Then I got an error "Table name "hits" cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing."

I tried to use the solutions from others like this

```
SELECT
    fullvisitorId,
    visitid,
    hit.hitnumber,
    (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 1) as productCategory,
    (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 2) as loyaltyClass,
    (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 3) as existingCustomer
FROM `<id>.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20180805'
```

Then I got another error Invalid table name: `<id>.ga_sessions_*` [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)].

Update: I even tried the most basic query

```
    SELECT
      *
    FROM [<id>.ga_sessions_20180805]
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) as hits
   LIMIT 10
```

Still returns the same error....

What is the error that I made for both script? And how can I get the custom dimension value?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use  case when which is supported by all

```
    SELECT
    fullvisitorId,
    visitid,
    h.hitnumber,
    case when x.index = 1 then x.value end as productCategory,
    case when x.index = 2 then x.value end as loyaltyClass,
    case when x.index = 3 then x.value end as existingCustomer
    FROM [<id>.ga_sessions_20180805]
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST( hits ) as h
   WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20180805'
```

**Note: enable standard SQL for the query, or use the new BigQuery UI**

Comment: Thanks for the help first!I replace the ID, but it still returns the same problem...which is: Table name "hits" cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing.

Comment: @PakHangLeung i edited answer i think as of alis used h for hit so in selection hit will not find as a result it produce error

Comment: You need to enable standard SQL for the query, or use the new BigQuery UI.

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin Unfortunately still does not work .. even tried to use simply a select *, still have the same problem .

Comment: @PakHangLeung could you please just SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(hits) just wondering what will return want to know and please check just select * from  [<id>.ga_sessions_20180805] is there table exist or not

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Actually the problem was because in original setting, the legacy SQL option is selected. Shut it down then it works. But thanks again for your help ;-)

Comment: @PakHangLeung i am going to add that portion in answer you can accept it as a others help

Answer (score 4):

In  your first query - you should just fix table reference in below line

```
FROM [<id>.ga_sessions_20180805],UNNEST(hits) as hit
```

to something like

```
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.ga_sessions_20180805`,UNNEST(hits) as hit
```

Similar fix for second query, but in addition - alias `h` should be replaced with `hit`  as below

```
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS hit
```

Note: above is for BigQuery Standard SQL - so you can add to the very top of your query below line as a first line

```
#standardSQL
```

For example

```
#standardSQL     
SELECT
  fullvisitorId,
  visitid,
  hit.hitnumber,
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 1) as productCategory,
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 2) as loyaltyClass,
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 3) as existingCustomer
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.ga_sessions_20180805`,UNNEST(hits) as hit 
LIMIT 100
```